# Get one variant in Shopify

Tags: shopify, variants

My products have 2 variants, size and color. I want to display the size options as a series of buttons. Here's my current code:

```
{% for variant in product.variants %}
  <input type="button" name="{{ variant.id }}" id="{{ variant.id }}" value="{{ variant.title }}">
{% endfor %}
```

This returns buttons with values like S/White, M/White, L/White, etc. I want just S, M and L. Pulling from of the example code in the docs, I've tried

```
{% for variant in product.variants.size %}
```

and

```
{% for variant in product.variants.first %}
```

but evidently that's not the right syntax as nothing is output.

What's the correct way to do this?

TIA - Joe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variants contain up to 3 options. In your case, `variant.option1` will give you the size (S/M/L) and `variant.option2` is the colour. You can also get the titles of the options with `product.options`. [See the doco here](http://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-variables/product#variant) for more info on variants.

Also, have you seen [this tutorial](http://docs.shopify.com/manual/configuration/store-customization/showcasing-products/add-color-swatches-to-your-products) on adding colour swatches and buttons to a product page? Maybe some of the code for creating the buttons would help you get started.

**EDIT:**

By following the tutorial mentioned above, you can get buttons for the size options like this:

[image]

Put this code in **product.liquid** below `</select>`:

```
{% if product.available and product.variants.size > 1 %}
  {% include 'swatch' with 'Size' %}
{% endif %}
```

If you also want buttons for the color option (and not swatches), use this code in **product.liquid**:

```
{% if product.available and product.variants.size > 1 %}
  {% for option in product.options %}
    {% include 'swatch' with option %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

And delete these lines from **swatch.liquid** (line 30):

```
{% if downcased_option contains 'color' or downcased_option contains 'colour' %}
  {% assign is_color = true %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thanks for responding, Steph, but I'm not able to integrate .option1 and get the results I'm looking for. I tried `<input type="button" name="{{ variant.option1.id }}" id="{{ variant.option1.id }}" value="{{ variant.option1.title }}">` and `{% for variant in product.variants.option1 %}` but neither worked. Can you give me the proper syntax? And, yes, I am familiar with that tutorial - I've got it working; I'll take a deeper look at the code to see what I can uncover.

Comment: @JoeLowery See my edit above for how to use the color swatch tutorial to get the buttons working. That's probably the simplest way to do it.

Comment: Thanks so much, Steph. Sorry for my delayed acceptance of your answer. It worked perfectly.